# Key in string as parameter input, returns error message 'Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.'

Tags: sql-server

I am facing problem with SQL Server, I have created a stored procedure with parameters in as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertTblBatch] 
     (@VoucherNo [NVARCHAR](20),
      @Reference [NVARCHAR](50),
      @VoucherDate [DATETIME],
      @ProductCode [NVARCHAR](30),
      @WareHouse [NVARCHAR](20),
      @Type [CHAR](10),
      @batch [NVARCHAR](50),
      @Factor1 [NVARCHAR](50),
      @Factor2 [NVARCHAR](50),
      @MfgDate [DATETIME],
      @ExpDate [DATETIME],
      @Quantity [FLOAT],
      @LineNo [NUMERIC](18, 0),
      @IsBatch [INT],
      @Flag [INT],
      @Code [NVARCHAR](20),
      @ReplacedFor [NVARCHAR](20),
      @StockOutCostPrice [FLOAT],
      @EngineNo [NVARCHAR](30),
      @LicenseNo [NVARCHAR](30))
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO tblBatchSerialNos ([VoucherNo], [Reference], [VoucherDate],[ProductCode], [WareHouse], [Type], [SerialNo], [Factor1], [Factor2], [MfgDate], [ExpDate], [Quantity], [LineNo], [IsBatch], [Flag], [Code], [ReplacedFor], [StockOutCostPrice], [EngineNo], [LicenseNo]) 
    VALUES (@VoucherNo, @Reference, @VoucherDate, @ProductCode, @WareHouse, @Type, @batch, @Factor1, @Factor2, @MfgDate, @ExpDate, @Quantity, @LineNo, @IsBatch, @Flag, @Code, @ReplacedFor, @StockOutCostPrice, @EngineNo, @LicenseNo)
```

While I tried to key in '2018.05.16' as input for `@batch`, SQL Server returns an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

I cannot specific the `@batch` as `datetime` because the input is not only date, it can be 'AA-20' or 'OB-CS004A' and etc. The `@batch` is input for column `[SerialNo]`, the data type for this column is `nvarchar(50)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the value in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. It can be converted into date datatype.

Eg. YYYY-MM-DD format. 2018-05-16

```
SELECT CAST('2018-05-16' AS DATE)
```

Check whether the @batch is date value before inserting to the date column. you can use the [IsDate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DECLARE @batch nvarchar(60) = '2018-05-16'
SELECT ISDATE(@batch) -- 1
SET @batch = 'AA-20'
SELECT ISDATE(@batch) -- 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I cannot use this way, if i key in 'OB-CS004A' as input then it would appear error. '2018.05.16' is one of the possible input only, I want to store the value as string instead of date.

Comment: @sat, if the datatype of SerialNumber is NVARCHAR(50), you should not be getting error as nvarchar to datetime. I think there is something wrong with some other input value of the stored procedure, which is being inserted into the table datetime column.

Comment: thank you for your reply, it is other input into datetime column affect the stored procedure, you give me hint and save my day, thank you very much.